# Pynput seems to conflict with pyautogui when defining hotkeys and simulating mouse clicks

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

My goal is to use custom hotkeys to execute different funcions in Python. I found Pynput by googling. Here is the official example from Pynput documentation (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#controlling-the-keyboard):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_activate():
    print('Global hotkey activated!')

def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
    keyboard.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<alt>+h'),
    on_activate)
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```

I only a few lines of pyautogui commands. So my code looks like this:

```
from pynput import keyboard
import pyautogui, time

def on_activate_h():
    pyautogui.click(1000, 500)
    pyautogui.click(1000, 600)
##    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.click(1000, 700)
    pyautogui.click(1000, 800)
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+h pressed')

def on_activate_i():
    print('<ctrl>+<alt>+i pressed')

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': on_activate_h,
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+i': on_activate_i}) as h:
    h.join()
```

When executing the code, some weird stuff happens. When pressing "Ctrl+Alt+h" for the first one or two times, it looks fine. Then I found that pressing "Ctrl+Alt" will execute the code in the on_activate_h() function too.

When I remove one line of the four pyautogui.click() lines, the problem seems gone. However, when pressing "Ctrl+Alt+h" twice in a row very quick, the problem comes back.

I tried to solve the problem by inserting the line "time.sleep(0.5)" to Line 7, but it doesn't work. The problem persists.

I'm a self-taught novice programmer who learnt some Python online at automatetheboringstuff.com. So the problem seems really weired to me. Could someone help me solve this? Or is there a better way to define different hotkeys to run different codes? Thanks in advance. I would be very grateful for any solutions.

Comment: You have used `pynput`.Why didn't you control your mouse by only using `pynput`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Good idea, but there's still something wrong. See this post from me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61764725/pynput-doesnt-work-as-intended-regarding-mouse-clicking-and-button-pressing

Comment: @wbzy00 I ran into a very similar problem using pynput's GlobalHotKeys() in combination with pyautogui. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @jub No, I have discarded this script.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was able to get it working. Try releasing the 'h' as the first step in `on_activate_h()`, and then insert a time.sleep() before the first pyautogui click. The problem seems to be the script is executing faster than the operating system can respond to the simulated inputs.