# Interaction between PyAutoGui and Pynput // Threading

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I am currently writing some hotkey "macros" using python for a software which has bad usability and no API to speak off. I have no real experience/background in python programming (or really programming in general), just some general knowledge and small side projects.
The programm I am writing is supposed to repond to hotkey combinations and then click certain interface elements by locating them via image matching with openCV. This general works fine. The problematic behaviour is, that after some initial hotkey usages it seems that somewhere down the line a key value is registered which is not currently pressed, which leads to hotkeys firing off, when only 2 out of 3 needed keys are pressed.

The combination alt + shift + J does something. After initially using it, it seems that the "J" key is registered as pressed till I use another hotkey (p.e. shift+alt+K). This leads to the "J"-Function beeing executed, when I am only pressing alt + shift.

It seems some other people had the same problem, see here [Pynput seems to conflict with pyautogui when defining hotkeys and simulating mouse clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751545/pynput-seems-to-conflict-with-pyautogui-when-defining-hotkeys-and-simulating-mou) (sadly no solution there) or here [PySimpleGUI breaks pynput. How do I combine them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68055734/pysimplegui-breaks-pynput-how-do-i-combine-them) (I sadly am not quite sure how to adapt threading to my program. My first naive attempt at simply wrapping the with-statement into an extra thread didn't solve the issue.)

Here's my code (I am aware that it probably is really really un-optimized, especially regarding my "click"-function):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import mouse
import sys
import time
from pynput import keyboard as kb

# insert needle images here. p.e. advanced selection, matrix wiz etc...
designButtonImage = cv2.imread('needle_images/designButton.png', cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
navigationButtonImage = cv2.imread('needle_images/navigationButton.png', cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
dataEntyButtonImage = cv2.imread('needle_images/dataEntryButton.png', cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
openItemsButtonImage = cv2.imread('needle_images/openItemsButton.png', cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
tagetikRibbon = cv2.imread('needle_images/tgk_ribbon.png', cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)


allNeedleImages = [designButtonImage, 
                   navigationButtonImage, 
                   dataEntyButtonImage, 
                   openItemsButtonImage, 
                   tagetikRibbon
                   ]

def search(needleImage):
    
    image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pyautogui.screenshot()), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(image, needleImage, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    
    minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    w = needleImage.shape[1]
    h = needleImage.shape[0]

    return [minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc, result, w, h]
 
def click(needleImageMetaDataIndex):
        
    initialMousePos = pyautogui.position()
    needleImageMetaData = search(allNeedleImages[needleImageMetaDataIndex])
  
    if needleImageMetaData[1] >= 0.75:
        mouse.move(int(needleImageMetaData[3][0]+needleImageMetaData[5]/2), int(needleImageMetaData[3][1]+needleImageMetaData[6]/2))
        mouse.click("left")
          
    else: 
        tgkRibbonMetaData = search(tagetikRibbon)
        if tgkRibbonMetaData[1] > 0.90:

            mouse.move(int(tgkRibbonMetaData[3][0]+tgkRibbonMetaData[5]/2), int(tgkRibbonMetaData[3][1]+tgkRibbonMetaData[6]/2))   
            mouse.click("left")
            time.sleep(0.05)
            needleImageMetaData = search(allNeedleImages[needleImageMetaDataIndex])
            mouse.move(int(needleImageMetaData[3][0]+needleImageMetaData[5]/2), int(needleImageMetaData[3][1]+needleImageMetaData[6]/2))
            mouse.click("left")
        else:
            pass
    
    mouse.move(initialMousePos[0],initialMousePos[1])


def clickDesign():
    click(0)
def clickNavigation():
    click(1)
def clickDataEntry():
    click(2)
def clickOpenItems():
    click(3)

def kill_script():
    kb.Listener.stop
    print("0")
    sys.exit()

with kb.GlobalHotKeys(
        {'<alt>+<shift>+J': clickDesign,
         '<alt>+<shift>+K': clickNavigation,
         '<alt>+<shift>+L': clickDataEntry,
         '<alt>+<shift>+Ö': clickOpenItems,
         '<alt>+<shift>+Q': kill_script}) as h:
        h.join()
```

I'd be grateful for all help I can get, thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe PySimpleHotkey project could be of help? It shows 1 way of working with hotkeys and PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input. I had a look at it and I sadly can't just use it as it's actions seem to be limited. But maybe I'll be able to adapt it.

Comment: I didn't think you would be able to directly use it. It is merely a "reference design"... one way of working with hotkeys. Thought maybe it could give you some ideas or approaches. Good luck with your project. It's ambitious for a beginner.

Comment: Ah thanks I see! It's definitely something I should do.